# Что установить в Visual studio 2017 для изучения C# по книге Эндрю Стиллмена и Дженнифер Грин "Изучаем C#"?

Tags: c#

Решила установить Visual Studio 2017 для изучения по книге Эндрю Стиллмена и Дженнифер Грин "Изучаем C#"(3-е издание,ISBN: 978-5-496-00867-9).
Столкнулась с тем, что в книге написано "раскройте раздел Visual C#, выделите строчку Windows Store и выберите вариант Blank App(XAML)", а у меня всё выглядит иначе. Поскольку я начинающий, хотелось бы спросить совета, что установить, чтобы понимать книгу? Спасибо! [image: 3[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRzah.jpg)

Comment: что мешает установить VS той версии, которая используется в книге?

Answer (score 2):

Насколько я понял в книге рассматривается WPF. Поэтому Вам однозначно нужна "Разработка классических приложений .NET".

Вообще, данная книга вышла ещё в 2014 году и потому уже в значительной степени устарела. Современных технологий там нет. Да и VS, как Вы сами видите несколько изменилась.

Рекомендую, если есть такая возможность, поискать книги 2018-2019 годов.